# When to consider the velocity of the other reference frame?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, velocity, observers

Let's say I have a spaceship going away from the Earth with speed $V=3/5c$ and it emits a light signal back to Earth when 1h in hit it spaceship time. This is the problem presented in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LeaJdT70zQ) video and I'm not quite understanding the logic behind the resolution.

When I'm **on Earth** and want to calculate the time when that signal arrives on my clock, I do not consider the speed of the spaceship because the speed of light is the same in all inertial reference frames. That's what he does in problem b. However, in problem c, if I'm **on the spaceship** and want to calculate the time the signal arrives back at Earth, I then have to consider that the Earth is moving away at speed $V = 3/5c$ and the distance traveled by light is $x' = (c+v)t'$.

But I don't understand why in this case the speed is not just $c$ also. I'm quite confused on when to consider the relative speeds and when not.

Comment: If a policeman is chasing you, do you see why running faster will delay your capture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't understand why in this case the speed is not just c also

The speed of the light pulse is indeed just $c$ in both cases.

However, you are interested in the time it takes for the light pulse from the rocket to reach the earth. That depends on the speed of the earth too.

That principle holds in both frames. In both frames the important speed is the closing speed. The difference is that in the Earth’s frame the Earth is stationary so the closing speed simplifies to the speed of light.